# How to make a kills counter in Unity2D with C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui, topdown

I want to make a kill counter but for some reason it's not working.
*Here is what i did*
I create a new empty GameObject `Game Manager` And add a new component `Score`, Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text kills_UI;
    private int Kills_Counts; //How many kills
    
    public void Increase_score() //This will update the UI text to the current kills count 
    {
        Kills_Counts++;
        kills_UI.text = Kills_Counts.ToString();
    }
}
```

After that i called this function in the enemy script `BulletColision` after he is killed :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletColision : MonoBehaviour
{
    Score kills_score;

    void Start()
    {
        kills_score = GetComponent<Score>();
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D others) //When a bullet collide with en enemy prefab 
    {
        if (others.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject); //Destroy the enemy
            kills_score.Increase_score(); //Calling the function from 'GameManager'
            Destroy(others.gameObject); //Destroy the bullet
            
        }
            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `kills_score` reference, if you do:

```
kills_score = GetComponent<Score>();
```

You are searching for `Score` component on your `BulletCollision`, which I guess do not have `Score` component since it's a bullet.

**Quick fix:**

Attach to your `GameManager` a new `TAG` like "GameManager", then use

```
kills_score = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<Score>();
```

instead of

```
kills_score = GetComponent<Score>();
```

To quickly validate this make your score variable `public` and see in your editor if the reference is correctly set.

*Also and as a side note, try to maintain your variables with lowerCamelCame nomenclature, meaning that starts with lower case.*